# Go to URL if draggable div reaches top or bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, plugins

I have a draggable div. If I move to the top it should redirect to link1. If I move to the bottom it should redirect to link2.

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Ln8/)

I think I could add something like this?

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (document.body.scrollHeight == 
        document.body.scrollTop +        
        window.innerHeight) {
        location.href='http://google.com';

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    // epsilon is a constant representing the tolerance
    // you can adjust it as you like;
    var epsilon = 10;
    if(event.y < epsilon &&
        $('#move').hasClass('pep-active')){ // check if the element is being dragged
            location.href='http://google.com';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3Ln8/2/
The fiddle might seem not to work, but check the console to see that you are not being redirrected for security reasons (cross-origin iframe).

**EDIT:**
both top and bottom link:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    var epsilon = 10;
    if(event.y < epsilon &&
        $('#move').hasClass('pep-active')){
            location.href='http://google.com';
    }
    if(document.documentElement.clientHeight - event.y < epsilon &&
       $('#move').hasClass('pep-active')){
            location.href='http://yahoo.com';
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh great! It works :) Would it possible to add another link für bottom?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cool library! It was fun to learn about!

[pep](http://pep.briangonzalez.org/) has an option called `rest` that is a function that gets called when it stops moving. I then test to see if it is close to the bottom or top. I could not redirect the iframe, so I used an `alert` to demonstrate, replace it with your redirect code.

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
      // pep is super simple...but there are wayyy
      // more options doc'd on github.
      $('#move').pep({
          'rest': function () {
              if (($('#move')[0].style.top.replace('px', '') * 1) < 100) {
                  alert('Hit top');
              } else if (($('#move')[0].style.top.replace('px', '') * 1) > (window.innerHeight - 250)) {
                  alert('Hit bottom');
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

#### fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/t3Ln8/3/

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Just tried, can't see the alert :(

Comment: How close to the top do you want it to trigger at?

Comment: If possible 50px top, 50px bottom :)

Comment: Could you help me with the links? Doesn't work on mobile devices. This is my fiddle jsfiddle.net/t3Ln8/6